# Changing :before value on button click CSS style and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble changing the color of :before on a button click event. At the moment, I've got code which changes the background to red when I call the changeColor(); function but doesn't change the :before section which is the "tick" on a chat bubble I'm coding. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Please see the code below:

```
HTML:
<p id="chatLog"></p>

CSS:
body {
background: #368dda;
}

.p {
position: relative;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
width: 300px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 40px;
padding: 24px;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
}

.p:before {
 content: "";
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 border-left: 24px solid #fff;
 border-right: 12px solid transparent;
 border-top: 12px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
 left: 32px;
  bottom: -24px;
}

Javascript:
function changeColor() {
document.getElementById('chatLog').style.backgroundColor = `red`;
return false;     
}
```

Comment: You can not access pseudo elements via JS, all you are doing here is setting the background color of the `p` element itself. If the color you need to set is not "dynamic" - then don't set inline styles (that is something you should avoid as far as possible to begin with), but add a class to the element - and add a rule to your stylesheet, that formats the pseudo element differently, when its "parent" has that class. If you really need to set a dynamic color value here - then you will have to take the "detour" via CSS variables.

Comment: You can use `background: inherit`.

Comment: @Shikkediel, yes, if they want the same background for both the element and the pseudo, that would work. But I couldn't really tell if that's actually what they wanted.

Comment: Thanks guys! I used background: inherit in the end but I appreciate the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has access to the DOM, but a pseudo element is generated by the css. You'd need to instead just toggle an additional css class to overwrite the original pseudo attributes attached to the element that supplies the pseudo as such.

```js
doStuff = () => {
  const example = document.getElementById('special-p');
  example.classList.toggle('green-before');
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: gray 1px dotted;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
}

.green-before {
  color: #000;
}
.green-before:before {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<p id="special-p">The lazy brown dog jumps over the fence.</p>

<button onclick="doStuff()">Do Stuff</button>
```

You can also look at `background: inherit` to allow the pseudo's to inherit attributes by the parent.